# Can a DHCP reservation use an IP address in the exclusion range?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, ip-address, dhcp-server

Windows Server 2008 R2, running the DHCP service.

```
DHCP Scope: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
Exclusions: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.99
```

If a reservation uses an IP address in the exclusion range (like `192.168.1.42`), what will happen when that specific client makes a DHCP request?
Will it get the reserved address (even if it's excluded from the scope) or will it get another, casual one?

Comment: Explanation: I want to exclude a range of statically-assigned IP addresses from DHCP, but I also want some network printers which are automatically configured with DHCP to get a fixed address in that range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will get the address.  In one network I manage all of the reservations are in the excluded range.

From the technet docs.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737055(v=WS.10).aspx

> Reservations can be created using any IP address in the scope’s
>   address range, even if the IP address is also within an exclusion
>   range.